# How to Pull Data from a Website Without a Public API

Tags: angularjs

I'm primarily a back-end developer and I consistently run into this problem. As a working example, I want to pull historical data for baseball players from a website called fangraphs. The problem is that this website, while incredibly useful, simply refuses to release a public API. How can I work around this? I am writing an AngularJS application and I just don't see how I can pull data from this site in an automated fashion. As an example, let's say I want to pull PITCHf/x Pitch Velocity data for Noah Syndergaard from this [page](http://www.fangraphs.com/statss.aspx?playerid=11762&position=P). How can I do so in order to use it in my application?

Thank you!

Comment: Use cURL and identify where the information you require is? Without an API, this will be difficult, and prone to breakage if the main site does any changes. It will also be very slow.

Comment: How do you specify "where the information you require is."

Comment: I suggest you read up here: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: I do not believe cURL plays nicely with JavaScript. I have used AJAX requests before, but this website is not using REST API so I don't understand how to request certain entries in the various tables.

Comment: You should use selenium to extract data from this kinda site..